# Cassini and the Huygens Probe

Tags: saturn

Why is Cassini self destructing in Saturn's atmosphere while the Huygens Probe was sent to land on Titan?

Comment: I think I need some more clarity on this one. Are you wondering why Cassini isn't being landed like Huygens was? Are you wondering why Cassini is being self-destructed while Huygens is still around?

Comment: Or is this what you are wondering about? https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21295/58